# DAX - Counting as Zero during Filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

In powerbi I have two tables.

One table called Date. This is marked as a date table and has a date column called "Date and a column called "endofMonth" which is the last day of the month in Date column.

The second table is called staffmaster. This has a unique id column. It has columns called "Start Date" and "End Date". There is also column for "Business Area".

There is a relationship from Date[Date] to Staffmaster[start date].

I have the following Dax code set up to create a measure.

```
EmployeesAtEndOfMonth = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED('staffmaster'[Business Area]),  
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('staffmaster'[Unique ID]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('staffmaster'),
            ('staffmaster'[End Date] >= MAX('Date'[End of Month]) || ISBLANK('staffmaster'[End Date])) &&
            'staffmaster'[Start Date] <= MAX('Date'[End of Month]) &&
            'staffmaster'[Business Area] IN VALUES ('STAFFMASTER'[Business Area])
        )
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('staffmaster'[Unique ID]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('staffmaster'),
            ('staffmaster'[End Date] >= MAX('Date'[End of Month]) || ISBLANK('staffmaster'[End Date])) &&
            'staffmaster'[Start Date] <= MAX('Date'[End of Month])
        )
    )
)
```

This measure calculates perfectly when nothing is selected on a slicer. However when I select (for example) "HR" as the business area (using a slicer), then I get some errors in that for each month where we had a new start, the measure shows the correct staff count, but if there were no new starts, then it shows blank.

Its not counting the new starts, its counting how many employees there were. But why in those months with no new starts is it defaulting to blank?

Answer (score 0):

DAX shows blank when the value is zero.
You can simply add +0 after your distinctcount forumalas (before the commas) to force zeroes rather than blanks.

Comment: But thats just it, These months arent zero. 
For example if i have no slicer selected, then my staff counts all show perfect for each month.

If I select a slicer, for example "HR", then it shows Jan23 - 100, Feb 23 - 105, Mar23 - 102, Apr23 - blank, May23 - 102. 

Just an example obviously but rather odd. The correlation with the blanks is that in this instance "HR" didnt have any new starters that month. If I swapped to "Sales", then it shows Jan23 - 200, Feb 23 - blank, Mar23 - 205, Apr23 - 198, May23 - blank
Again the correlation is sales had no new starts  in Feb or May

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the filtering then. Have you tried removing the isfiltered logic. perhaps something like this?

```
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('staffmaster'[Unique ID])+0,
    FILTER(
        ALL('staffmaster'),
        ('staffmaster'[End Date] >= MAX('Date'[End of Month]) || ISBLANK('staffmaster'[End Date])) &&
        'staffmaster'[Start Date] <= MAX('Date'[End of Month]) &&
        'staffmaster'[Business Area] IN VALUES ('STAFFMASTER'[Business Area])
    )
)
```